# Can I work remotely while in the UK on a working holiday visa?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, taxes, working-visas

I'm a dual citizen of the United States and Canada. I work and live in the United States. I'd like to visit the United Kingdoms for a year on a working holiday visa (acquired as a Canadian), while continuing with my current job remotely.

Am I allowed to work remotely while on this visa? If so, what exactly is the tax situation with this?

Comment: The Working Holiday visa does not exist any more. Parts of it were merged into the T5 Youth Mobility Scheme. You'll need to be more specific about which part of T5 (YMS) you are applying for.